importing related classes and functions from different .py files
I want to separate the classes and functions which ara in a single .py script into different .py scripts to be tidy. for example, my_functions.py and my_class.py. but some functions contain "my_class.py" 's class parameters or attributes. for example:
def tlbo_dm_continuous(pop, itr):
    if group_number == 0:
        variable = len(frame_veri)
    else:
        variable = group_number
    """sınıf oluştur"""
    X = np.array([lower + np.random.random(variable) * (upper - lower) for i in range(pop)])
    F = np.array([]) #cezalandırılmış amaç fonksiyonu
    Psi = np.array([]) #ceza katsayısı
    for s in range(pop):
        Bar2D.reset()
        for j in bar:  # çubuk eleman verilerinin örneklenmesi
            if group_number == 0:
                bar[j].area = X[s][j - 1]
            else:
                bar[j].area = X[s][bar[j].group - 1]
        Bar2D.Sys_sol()
        psi = (1 + Bar2D.fi + Joint2D.fi) ** 2
        F = np.append(F, (psi * Bar2D.W))
        Psi = np.append(Psi, psi)

"tlbo_dm_continuous" function contains "Bar2D.Sys_sol()" class attribute.
when i import "tlbo_dm_continuous" from "my_functions.py" and "Bar2D" from "my_class.py", i get some warning.
how can i overcome from this trouble?
